# Reading content of HTML File through Node js

Tags: node.js, server

```
const http=require('http');
const fs=require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  //Open a file on the server and return its content:
  fs.readFile('./index.html',null, (err, data) => {
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
      res.write(data);
      return res.end();
    });

}).listen(8080);

I am newbie in node js.Just started learning nodejs recently.
```

Getting this error while trying to Reading content of HTML File through Nodejs. I have updated
npm module but it is not working.->
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(

```
   ^TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an 
   instance 
of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received undefined
←[90m    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)←[39m
←[90m    at write_ (node:_http_outgoing:742:11)←[39m
←[90m    at ServerResponse.write (node:_http_outgoing:707:15)←[39m
    at ReadFileContext.callback (H:\node\nodetutorial\coremodule\Readingdata.js:8:11)
←[90m    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (node:fs:314:13)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'←[39m
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `res.write()` function cannot accept an undefined object (which is what you're passing right now). Try stringifying your response like this:

`res.write(JSON.stringify(data));`

Additionally, check why `data` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

The path to the `./index.html` file is probably incorrect. You can find out what directory you're currently in by executing `console.log(__dirname)`. You can either change the path to the file (eg: `./../index.html`) or move the file according to the output.